# How to time code execution in TeX?

Tags: programming, performance

Throughout time, during my conversations with members of TeX Exchange, I ran across a few ways to time execution of the code. But the pieces of this information are scattered throughout my account's activity log. To save time and to have a dedicated place for the purpose of timing TeX code, I ask this question.

Above all, I would like to know whether there are plain TeX solutions, or at least LaTeX 2ε solutions, so I would prioritize them over LaTeX3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a `\benchmark{<n>}{<code>}`, which will run `<code>` `<n>` times and measures the elapsed time. The overhead of the loop is minimal, so you usually don't need to worry about that.

There's also a `\benchmarkTIC` and a `\benchmarkTOC` command. `\benchmarkTIC` will reset the timer, and `\benchmarkTOC` will measure the time since the last `\benchmarkTIC` and will print it to the terminal.

This is mostly copied from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/456322/134574), but slightly improved and with added `tic`/`toc` commands. All of this is just a subset of the features of `l3benchmark`, so I suggest you use that instead. `l3benchmark` has a `\benchmark:n` command which automatically fires out the number of repetitions necessary, and also has `\benchmark_tic:` and `\benchmark_toc:` commands which allow nesting (the ones in the code below don't).

The code below prints this to the terminal:

```
> 1000 feature tests done (0.976s)
> Benchmark TIC:
> Benchmark TOC: 0.97699s
```

The essence is using the pdfTeX primitives `\pdfresettimer` and `\pdfelapsedtime`. The first bunch of lines is just a basic setup so that the code works in more engines. LuaTeX doesn't have the primitives, so their behaviour is emulated with Lua function calls. XeTeX and ε-(u)pTeX have the same primitives under the names `\resettimer` and  `\elapsedtime` (which makes sense, since they are not PDF-related things). The code normalises eveything to `\resettimer` and `\elapsedtime`.

`\resettimer` resets an internal (let's call it) timer in the engine to zero, and `\elapsedtime` retrieves the value from that timer (in scaled seconds: 1 s × 65536).

`\benchmark` does `\resettimer` at the very beginning, loops the code as many times as requested, and pretty-prints `\elapsedtime` at the end. `\benchmarkTIC` and `\benchmarkTOC` are just wrappers around `\resettimer` and `\elapsedtime` to write stuff to the terminal and convert the time from scaled seconds to seconds.

```
\begingroup
  \ifcase 0%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname pdfresettimer\endcsname\relax\else1\fi % pdfTeX
    \expandafter\ifx\csname directlua\endcsname\relax\else2\fi % LuaTeX
    \expandafter\ifx\csname resettimer\endcsname\relax\else3\fi % Others
    \relax
      \errmessage{Primitive support for timing unavailable}
  \or \endgroup
    \let\resettimer\pdfresettimer
    \let\elapsedtime\pdfelapsedtime
  \or \endgroup
    \def\resettimer{\directlua{pdfelapsedtimer_basetime = os.clock()}}
    \def\elapsedtime{\directlua{tex.print((os.clock()-pdfelapsedtimer_basetime)*65536)}}
  \or \endgroup
  \fi
\catcode`@=11
\let\benchmark@reset\resettimer
\let\benchmark@elapsed\elapsedtime
\begingroup
\def\benchmark@time@s{\strip@pt\dimexpr\benchmark@elapsed sp\relax s}
\def\benchmark@term{\immediate\write17}
\edef\x{\endgroup\def\noexpand\rem@pt##1.##2\detokenize{pt}}%
  \x{#1\ifnum#2>\z@.#2\fi}
\def\strip@pt{\expandafter\rem@pt\the}%
\def\benchmark@output#1{\benchmark@term{> #1 feature tests done (\benchmark@time@s)}}
\long\def\benchmark@runNtimes#1#2{%
  \ifnum#1>0\relax\expandafter\benchmark@Ntimes@aux\number\numexpr#1-1;{#2}\fi}
\long\def\benchmark@Ntimes@aux#1;#2\fi{\fi #2\benchmark@runNtimes{#1}{#2}}
\long\def\benchmark#1#2{%
  \benchmark@reset \benchmark@runNtimes{#1}{#2}%
  \benchmark@output{#1}}
\def\benchmarkTIC{\benchmark@term{> Benchmark TIC:}\benchmark@reset}
\def\benchmarkTOC{\benchmark@term{> Benchmark TOC: \benchmark@time@s}}
\catcode`@=12

% Just for the example
\input tikz.tex

% Run some code a number of times
\benchmark{1000}
  {\setbox0\hbox{\tikz \draw (0,0) -- (1cm, 1cm);}}

% Benchmark some piece of code
\benchmarkTIC
\count0=0
\loop
\setbox0\hbox{\tikz \draw (0,0) -- (1cm, 1cm);}
\advance\count0 by 1
\ifnum\count0<1000
\repeat
\benchmarkTOC

\bye
```

Comment: @bp2017 :-) You don't _need_ to use `expl3`, but it feels a lot like reinventing a wheel